# YouTube API V3.0 request errors python

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, gdata, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to retrieve data from [YouTube Data API V3.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=en) python version.
Every request that i"m creating I'm getting the error:

> gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 410, 'body': 'No longer
>   available', 'reason': 'Gone'}

Here is my code:

```
import atom
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import gdata.youtube.data
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my_key'
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService(developer_key=DEVELOPER_KEY)
playlist_feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCBOYkdPkPF216lzhlqj2POw')
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You say you are using V3.  but your code is gdata which is v2.  V2 is deprecated. I suggest you switch to V3.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python

Comment: @DaImTo should i install the API again? I downloaded the API from https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client

Comment: That is not the API that is the client library, there is a difference.     That is the old gdata client library the new one can be found here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses the old Gdata library.   Which is YouTube API v2.

> The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March
>   4, 2014.

Your error:

```
{'status': 410, 'body': 'No longer available', 'reason': 'Gone'}
```

Makes me think that its down and doesn't work anymore, but I am going to have to look into that.  Either way I suggest you move to the new V3 API.  The new client library can be found here [Google apis Python client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)

**Update My assumption was correct.**

The YouTube V2 no longer works.  [bye by YouTube Data API V2](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.dk/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html)